# XLSX sheet js image placing issue in the second tab

Tags: javascript, image, xlsx, sheetjs

I am generated xlsx report with 2 tabs, also I place an image in the 2 tabs- The first tab contains the image but Tab2 not. Checked the worksheet and found that both the pages contain images section. but I don't know why the image does not appear in tab2. Any solution for this.

I used:

```
ws['!images'] = []; ws['!images'].push({ name: 'test1.jpeg', data: this.imgToDataUrl(imgData), opts: { base64: true }, type: 'jpeg', position: { type: 'twoCellAnchor', attrs: { editAs: 'oneCell' }, from: { col: 1, row: 1 }, to: { col: 4, row: 3 } } });
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you used? are there any errors?

Comment: ws['!images'] = [];
      ws['!images'].push({
        name: 'test1.jpeg',
        data: this.imgToDataUrl(imgData),
        opts: { base64: true },
        type: 'jpeg',
        position: {
          type: 'twoCellAnchor',
          attrs: { editAs: 'oneCell' },
          from: { col: 1, row: 1 },
          to: { col: 4, row: 3 }
        }
      });